# How to add custom validations for handsontable in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, handsontable

I'm using handsontable in angular 6.

I tried the code to add custom validations which is shown in the official documentation in my angular 6 component but it didn't work.

I searched several sites, but didn't find any single example that shows how to add custom validations in angular 2+ versions for handsOntable

Can anyone let me know how to register custom validations in angular 2+ versions

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created a sample custom validator for email and was able to set to a column

```
emailValidator = (value, callback) => {
  console.log(value)
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (/.+@.+/.test(value)) {
      callback(true);
    }
    else {
      callback(false);
    }
  }, 1000);
};

private columns: any[] = [
{
  data: 'name'
},
{
  data: 'email',
  validator: this.emailValidator,
  // Uncomment below line accept invalid input and indicate
  // allowInvalid: true
}
];

@ViewChild(HotTableComponent) hotTableComponent;
// Call validator after initialization
afterInit() {  this.hotTableComponent.getHandsontableInstance().validateCells(function(valid){});
```

afterInit is an event emitter

```
<hot-table [data]="data"
       [colHeaders]="colHeaders"
       [columns]="columns"
       [options]="options"
       (hotInstanceCreated)="instanceCreated($event)"
       (afterInit)="afterInit(event$)"
       [colWidths]="colWidths">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjmvq4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This works, but do you know how to validate all the cells by default when the table is loaded rather than validating while editing the cells?

Comment: Yes, this is currently possible by calling validateCells on the hotTable instance but do watch out for https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/5283 Have updated the answer/stackblitz with validation on load